# Can't login to local phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, osx-mavericks, phpmyadmin

Hy,

I've just installed MySQL and PHPMyadmin on my OS X Maverics, following this link: http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/downtown/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-osx-109-mavericks

After I download it, I've created a new local domain for it called "phpmyadmin.loc". I've configured up on the "phpmyadmin.loc/setup" page, as show in the link above.

I've typed in the username and the password which I set in the setup, pressed enter, and nothing happened. I've got a token in the link, the two fields (username and password) are gone empty and thats all. I can't login.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks, Dave.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Username = root
Password = (leave this blank)
```

Comment: I've tried it already, but won't help :\